# Is an editor's ability to change permissions settable (visible) in any of the APIs for Docs/ Drive?

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api

In Google Drive when I share something with another editor I can restrict their ability to change other's permissions or move the item.  Is that available through an API or SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to modify the writersCanShare attribute:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource